# Python: Is sqlite3.Cursor.execute lazy?

Tags: python, sqlite

Is the `sqlite3.Cursor.__iter__` method lazy? I.e. does it calculate all rows upfront and then yields them when iterated over, or does it calculate the rows only when I iterate over them? I am asking this because I am considering whether to add a `LIMIT` clause to my SQL queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SQLite C API is lazy; the [sqlite3_step](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/step.html) function computes the next result row on the fly.

As for Python's `sqlite3` module, the [source code](https://github.com/ghaering/pysqlite/blob/master/src/cursor.c) shows that the `pysqlite_cursor_iternext` function calls `pysqlite_step` once.

Comment: just for disambiguation, by ``pysqlite`` you mean the python DBI wrapper for SQLite, hosted on GitHub right?